# Detecting KeyUp events

Tags: dynamic, keyboard, eventhandler

Is there a way to detect when a key is released, similar to

```
EventHandler[InputField[], {"KeyDown", "k"} :> Print["k pressed"]]
```

It seems such detection isn't available at first glance, perhaps it can be achieved some other way?

Alternatively is there a way to detect which keys are currently pressed? I know that;

```
CurrentValue["ModifierKeys"]
```

Works for <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and such, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a list of regular keys being pressed.

Edit: `CurrentValue["EventKey"]` does not seem to work for this purpose as it only detects keydown events, thus you cannot do something like the following which detects shift-up

```
shiftDown = False;
Dynamic[
If[MemberQ[CurrentValue["ModifierKeys"], "Shift"], (shiftDown = True;), 
      If[shiftDown, (shiftDown = False; Print["Shift up code"])]
    ]
]
```

[link to MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/2Ky63zkr3xQ/discussion)

Comment: paging Yu-Sung Chang...

Comment: The fact that the _KeyDown_ event fires continuously while the key is pressed seems coherent with a timed scan of the keyboard, and not a real (interrupt driven) event handler. If that is the case, you'll never get a _KeyUp_ event.

Comment: If anyone knows for sure if this is the case, it would be nice with confirmation of this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  The reason is to keep things together for readers of both threads.

Comment: This isn't finished but the follow code works for registering key up events.  I am either going to link it in using MathKernel or convert it completely over to M code. [code here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=u7taCbPf)

Answer (score 6):

To answer the second part of your question, you can use `CurrentValue["EventKey"]` to get the current key that is being pressed. Modifying your example above:

```
EventHandler[InputField[], "KeyDown" :> Print[CurrentValue["EventKey"]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realize that you can detect which key triggered the event inside an event handler, however for the second part of my question I was looking for a way to cercumvent the lack of a keyup event, by having something similar to Dynamic[CurrentValue["ModifierKeys"]] which can be used to along with tricks to for example detect when shift is lifted.

Comment: `CurrentValue["EventKey"]` however does not detect all keys, only alphanumeric and punctuation keys, but no Control, Shift, Enter, etc.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: Updated to register any key presses**

Whenever an `EventHandler` does not handle something continuously, one can set up a listener manually using **scheduled tasks**. Here, the task `task` is initiated when the `InputField` is displayed, that scans the state of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. You can put whatever code you want to be evaluated on keypress in the `update` function.

```
DynamicModule[{task, pressed = {}, on = False, last, time, modNew, modOld, event = {}, 
  mods = {"AltKey", "CommandKey", "ControlKey", "OptionKey", "ShiftKey"}},
 Column@{
   Dynamic@pressed,
   EventHandler[
    InputField[], {"KeyDown" :> (If[! on, on = True]; last = SessionTime[];
                                 event = CurrentValue@"EventKey")}, 
    PassEventsDown -> True]
   },
 Initialization :> (
   modOld = False /@ mods;
   If[FreeQ[ScheduledTasks[], task], task = RunScheduledTask[
      time = SessionTime[];
      modNew = CurrentValue /@ mods;
      If[modNew =!= modOld, pressed = Pick[mods, modOld]];
      If[on && time - last > .55, on = False; pressed = {event}];
      modOld = modNew,
      .05]];
   ),
 Deinitialization :> If[MemberQ[ScheduledTasks[], task], RemoveScheduledTask@task]
 ]
```

Image shows the update due to successive key presses of any key (that can be registered):

[image]

For control keys, the method is simply checking `CurrentValue`-s while the `task` is running. The hard part is to get the letter/digit/punctuation keys to be registered. For those, the code measures the time between successive updates (`time` and `last`) which are calculated while the (non-control-)key is held pressed. Since Windows uses a 0.5 sec time delay before starting to flood-type when a key is pressed, one has to wait at least the same amount of time before being able to tell whether the key was released or it is still pressed and continuous typing is about to start. Thus registering the release of letter-keys can only happen when enough time (`.55` sec) has been spent since the last update.

Since the scheduled task should run in the background as long as the `InputField` is on screen, there should be a method to destroy it only when the `InputField` is destroyed, hence the `Deinitialization` code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've experimented with this kind of update, with no avail. If you could make it update `i` in "discrete steps" it would be a useful approach, but this still does not work: `old = False; i = 0; Dynamic[If[old =!= shift && shift, i++]; {shift, i}, old = shift; shift := CurrentValue@"ShiftKey"]`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Try `old = False; i = 0; Dynamic[If[old =!= shift && shift, i++]; old = shift; shift := CurrentValue@"ShiftKey"; {shift, i}]`

Comment: @Hector Well that's certainly a lot cleaner!

Comment: @Hector I just realized similar function is already in the question, and this is about *other* keys, not modifiers.  Oh well, it was fun playing with it.

Comment: I'm afraid without extension to letters etc., not just modifiers, this answer brings nothing new.  Do you think that's possible?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please check now. It is far from smooth or robust, but it is a proof of principle.

Comment: @Hector: while your code seems to work, it does not always register the press of the shift key, sometimes misses it (though `shift` changes, `i` is not increased).

Comment: Nice. Great idea!

Comment: @IstvánZachar: I can reproduce your statement if I press the shift key in rapid succession. I guess that happens because the routine was not completed before the next key press.

Answer (score 3):

This has been bugging non stop so I wanted to create a somewhat viable solution for Windows using autohotkey.

Run the following as an Administrator in autohotkey on Windows.

```
down=0

e::
    if(down=0){
      FileDelete, C:\Test.txt
      FileAppend, Down.`n, C:\Test.txt
      down=1
    }
return

e Up::
      Send e
      FileDelete, C:\Test.txt
      FileAppend, Up.`n, C:\Test.txt
      down=0
return
```

Then create the following

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];

ShowNETConsole["stdout"];
LoadNETType["System.Console"];
Console`Out@WriteLine["Hello from .NET"];

WatchFile[file_String, fun_] := 
  Module[{time, time2, w, e}, 
   w = NETNew["System.IO.FileSystemWatcher"];
   LoadNETType["System.IO.NotifyFilters"];
   LoadNETType["System.IO.File"];
   w@Path = FileNameJoin@Drop[FileNameSplit[file], -1];
   w@NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters`LastWrite;
   w@Filter = Last@FileNameSplit[file];
   e = AddEventHandler[w@Changed, myHandler];
   content = Import[file, "Plaintext"]; 
   myHandler[source_, e_] := (Catch[
      content2 = Import[file, "Plaintext"];
      If[content != content2, fun[source, e, content2];];
      content = content2;
      ]
     );
   w@EnableRaisingEvents = True;
   Return[{w, e}];];
WatchFile["C:\\Test.txt", Function[{w, e, content2},
  var = content2
  ]]
EventHandler[Dynamic@var, {"KeyDown" :> (Null;)}]
```

It will essentially allow the e key to detect when it is up and down.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using NotebookEventActions see the given example in an other subject.

```
displaying = True;

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions :> {{"KeyDown", "k"} :> (If[! displaying, 
      Print["k press"]]), 
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (If[! displaying, Print["down press"]]), 
   "MouseClicked" :> (If[displaying, displaying = False])}]
```

the related thread [Make EventHandler work for clicks and keys in a Dynamic display](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4167/make-eventhandler-work-for-clicks-and-keys-in-a-dynamic-display)

Comment: I fear this has the exact same problem, you cannot detect keyUp, since events only trigger on keyDown.

Comment: If it is really so crucial you may use JLink to call java API in mathematica. There defined key up events.

Answer (score 1):

One rather drastic solution is to use LibraryLink to just get the keyboard state directly from the operating system, and then deploy a high-frequency ScheduledTask to poll the keyboard state. I do this on Windows using C.

Here's a minimal working example, showing how to get the keyboard state into the kernel as a ByteArray, and then using EventHandler to change the color of a graphic when a certain key is pressed down, and to change it back as soon as the key is released.

In a separate file, library.c:

```
#include "WolframLibrary.h" 
#include "WolframNumericArrayLibrary.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h> 

DLLEXPORT int getKeyboardState(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){
    GetKeyState(0);
    BYTE keyboardState[256] = {0};
    if (GetKeyboardState(keyboardState)){
        MNumericArray keyboardByteArray;
        const mint length = 256;
        
        if (libData->numericarrayLibraryFunctions->MNumericArray_new(MNumericArray_Type_UBit8, 1, &length, &keyboardByteArray)) {
            return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
        }
       
        memcpy((uint8_t*) libData->numericarrayLibraryFunctions->MNumericArray_getData(keyboardByteArray), keyboardState, 256);
        MArgument_setMNumericArray(Res, keyboardByteArray);
        return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

    } else {
        return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    }
}
```

I use CCompilerDriver to compile this into a DLL, and then I load the function into the kernel and make some appropriate definitions.

```
<<CCompilerDriver`

CreateLibrary[
 File@"library.c", 
 "library.dll",
 "Libraries" -> {"User32.lib"},
 "Language" -> "C"
]

With[
 {func =
   LibraryFunctionLoad[
    File@"library.dll",
    "getKeyboardState",
    {}, ByteArray
    ]
  },
 keyboard[] := func[];
 keyboard[vk_Integer] := func[][[vk + 1]]
]
```

Now you can use this function in a ScheduledTask to poll the state a particular key.

```
color=Black;
w$pressed=.

EventHandler[
 Graphics[
  {Dynamic@color, Rectangle[],
   White, Arrow@{
     {.5, .5},
     Dynamic@MousePosition["Graphics", {.5, .5}]}
   }],
 {{"KeyDown", "w"} :>
   If[! TrueQ@w$pressed, (w$pressed = True;
     color = Purple;
     task = SessionSubmit@ScheduledTask[
        If[(keyboard[87]~Quotient~128) == 0,
         (TaskRemove@task;
          w$pressed = False;
          color = Black
          )], 1/100])]
  }
 ]
```

Select the resulting Graphics cell, and you'll see that the background color changes to purple as soon as the W key is pressed, and changes back again as soon as it's let go. Here's a GIF demonstrating: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQx5B.jpg

Unfortunately, this solution is specific to Windows, but I believe it should be easy to generalize this example.