# Is it possible to model the piano key attack?

Tags: sound, eventhandler

My purpose is to model the attack of a piano key. As the key is pressed a sound must be emitted. When the key is released the sound must stop with decreasing volume.

I have a partial success  when the time is fixed. For example, if time=2 then the following code simulates a key pressed for 2 seconds. But I don't know how to change it so that the sound stops (with a "natural feeling") immediately  after the key is released!

```
Button[Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]}],

 EmitSound[SampledSoundList[{{0.}}, 8000], "Preemptive"]; EmitSound[

  Play[(1 - E^(-30 t)) (1 - E^(-18 (time - t)))  Sin[ 
     2 Pi 440  t], {t, 0, time}]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I can't test it now but have you tried to use `EventHandler` with it's events? I'm not sure if the transition will be smooth but it is worth to try.

Comment: Detecting the release of the key is a tricky problem. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5246/862).