# Throttle the response to keystrokes in an EventHandler expression

Tags: eventhandler, date-and-time

What might be the most elegant way to throttle the `a`,`s` functions triggered by an `EventHandler` such that the `InputField` doesn't get to far behind in the following example?  Just to clarify.  I am looking to have the queued functions stop executing after either the `a` or `s` keys are released.

Here is an illustration of a similar issue to the one I am experiencing while in the `Graphics3D` element.

```
i = 0;
a[] := (Pause[RandomInteger[{1, 9}]*.1]; i++;);
s[] := (Pause[RandomInteger[{1, 9}]*.1]; i--;);
EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic@i, Number], {"KeyDown" :> (
    If[CurrentValue["EventKey"] == "a",
     a[], s[]
     ]
    )}
 ]
```

**EDIT:** If you hold down the a key I would like the unrun functions to either not run or somehow throttle the number of times the function is executed such that you can successfully hold down the a key for 2 seconds and then immediately(or as quickly as possible) hold down s key to subtract without a delay in the response.  Ideally I would like to use the `EventHandler` `KeyReleased` option but I am currently unable to get such key to work.

Comment: Just to clarify, does "too far behind" mean your example **should not** increment/decrement when I press a key multiple times during the pause or are you hoping for some type of buffered response?

Comment: @bobthechemist If you hold down the `a` key I would like the unrun functions to either not run or somehow throttle the number of times the function is executed such that you can successfully hold down the `a` key for 2 seconds and then immediately(or as quickly as possible) hold down `s` key to subtract without a delay in the response.

Comment: @bobthechemist I believe `KeyReleased` would make this process a lot easier although I have been unable to get such `EventHandler` to work currently

Comment: This I believe is a duplicate of this if not similar http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/detecting-keyup-events/112042#112042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a back-end for it and check the response time on that. Here's a little example of a back-end I've been working with:

```
$eventHandlerData =
  <|
   "ResponseDelay" -> Quantity[1, "Seconds"],
   "_ResponseDelay" :>
    With[{n = Now},
     AbsoluteTime[n + $eventHandlerData["ResponseDelay"]] -
      AbsoluteTime[n]
     ],
   "CallDelay" :>
    ($eventHandlerData[
       "_EventAbsoluteTime"] - $eventHandlerData[
       "LastCallAbsoluteTime"]),
   "LastCallEventTime" -> 0,
   "LastCallAbsoluteTime" -> 0,
   "x" -> Function[Print["!"]],
   "DefaultEvent" -> (Print[$eventHandlerData["EventKey"]] &)
   |>;
callEventHandler[] :=
  Catch[
   $eventHandlerData =
    Join[
     $eventHandlerData,
     Association@CurrentValue["EventData"],
     <|
      "EventKey" -> CurrentValue["EventKey"],
      "EventAbsoluteTime" -> CurrentValue["EventAbsoluteTime"],
      "_EventAbsoluteTime" -> AbsoluteTime[]
      |>];
   If[$eventHandlerData["_ResponseDelay"] > $eventHandlerData[
      "CallDelay"],
    Throw[$Failed]
    ];
   $eventHandlerData["LastCallAbsoluteTime"] =
    $eventHandlerData["_EventAbsoluteTime"];
   $eventHandlerData["LastCallTime"] =
    $eventHandlerData["EventAbsoluteTime"];
   Lookup[$eventHandlerData,
     $eventHandlerData@"EventKey",
     $eventHandlerData@"DefaultEvent"
     ][]
   ];
EventHandler[expr,
 {
  "KeyDown" :> callEventHandler[],
  {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> callEventHandler[],
  PassEventsDown -> False
  }
 ]
```

Note that I had to fall back to [`AbsoluteTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime.html) as I'm not entirely sure what the timings in `CurrentValue["EventAbsoluteTime"]` are.

You can then extend it to work in an indexable manner with `DynamicModule` that way you don't have to worry about cleaning up the backend when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work completely for reasons I don't know why, but the following seems to help some by using an `InputField` to monitor the keyboard input.

```
str = "";
i = 0;
a[] := (Pause[RandomInteger[{1, 9}]*.1]; i++;);
s[] := (Pause[RandomInteger[{1, 9}]*.1]; i--;);
Dynamic[Refresh[
  t = 0;
  Map[
   (If[# == "a", a[], s[]]) &,
   Select[StringSplit[str, ""], t++ < 3 &]
   ];
  str = "";
  , UpdateInterval -> 1], TrackedSymbols -> {}]
InputField[Dynamic@str, String, ContinuousAction -> True]
InputField[Dynamic@i, Number]
```

Comment: The following is relevant http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzF8sGTm