# Write GUI to select spheres in a grid

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, button

I'd like to generate a code that:

1) starts with a grid of circles (in general, it won't be a square grid)
2) allows the user to choose some of those circles
3) allows the user to choose the type of this circle (let's say, giving them different colors)
4) export the {x,y,type} for those circles.

I truly don't even know where to start. Is this worth doing with mathematica? If so, which functions am I looking for?

[image: image generated by selecting spheres in a grid]

Comment: How many types need to be selected?  If it is only two or perhaps three a modifier key or repeated clicking might be applicable.  More and you likely need some kind of menu.

Comment: probably 1-5 types. I think ideally I would 1st press a number, then click and that would assign this number-type to it.

Comment: Okay.  I posted a very basic example below with only one "type."  Please review it and then specify how you would like your actual method to differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want full flexibility you should try `EventHandler` and graphics primitives. If you can decipher the following example you will get the idea:

```
color = Black;
positions = Position[DiskMatrix[5], 1];
disks = {color, Disk[#, 0.4]} & /@ positions;

eventHandler[item : {c_, obj_: Disk[p_, _]}] := {c, EventHandler[obj,
   "MouseClicked" :> (disks = (disks /. item :> {color, obj}))
   ]}
mouseAppearance[obj_] := MouseAppearance[obj, "LinkHand"]

Deploy@Column[{
   Dynamic@Graphics[mouseAppearance@*eventHandler /@ disks, ImageSize -> 300],
   RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[color], {Black, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}]
   }, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image: Example]

In order to export your data you may define a function such as

```
types = {Black -> 0, Red -> 1, Green -> 2, Blue -> 3, Yellow -> 4};
export := disks /. {c_, Disk[pos_, _]} :> {c /. types, pos}
```

You mentioned that you might prefer keyboard shortcuts for the different colors. To achieve that I would start by trying to use `NotebookEventActions` as in [Make EventHandler work for clicks and keys in a Dynamic display](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4168/731).

Comment: I was planning in putting something like this together for "Step 3" today but I see I don't need to. +1

Comment: Combining this answer with @Mr.Wizard 'hex' and I have both cases I needed. EventHandler, Defer & Deploy were 3 new functions I had to learn. +2

Comment: @PFD I'm glad we could be of help.  Let us know if you have any problem with the final implementation.

Answer (score 5):

### Step 1

As a very quick example of how one might start, with the limitation of only one "type" available:

```
convert[Grid[m_?MatrixQ, ___]] := m[[All, All, 1]]

Defer[convert]@Grid[ConstantArray[RadioButton[], {4, 7}], Spacings -> {0.2, 0}]
```

Which outputs:

[image]

You then make a selection:

[image]

And evaluate it (the output), yielding:

```
{{False, False, False, True, False, False, False},
 {False, False, False, False, True, True, True},
 {False, False, True, False, False, False, False},
 {False, False, False, False, False, False, False}}
```

This could easily be converted to your {x,y,type} format with something like:

```
MapIndexed[Append[#2, #] &, %, {2}]
```

### Step 2

Still not addressing the need for multiple types but now with non-rectangular packing, easily generalized to arbitrary placement:

```
hex = Join @@ Array[{#2 + #, (#2 - #)/Sqrt[3]} &, {5, 5}, -2];

convert2[g_Graphics] := 
 Cases[g, Inset[RadioButton[value_, True], pos_] :> {value, pos}, -3]

Graphics[{
 Inset[RadioButton[], #] & /@ hex
}, ImageSize -> 150] // Defer[convert2]
```

[image]

And when evaluated:

```
{{False, {-4, 0}}, {True, {-3, 1/Sqrt[3]}}, . . .,
 {False, {3, -(1/Sqrt[3])}}, {False, {4, 0}}}
```

Comment: Besides the choice of types, how should I go about making a hexagonal - other than a square - grid of buttons? Other than that, your solution pretty much covers it. Tx.

Comment: @PFD Sorry, when you said "won't be a square grid" I thought you meant it would be a rectangular grid.  Can the elements *lie on* a rectangular grid (but some be missing around the periphery) or do the individual cells need a different "packing" such as hexagonal?

Comment: A meant a different packing, but 99.9% of the case it will be either square or hexagonal. I think I can work with a generalized case if I can understand how to make a hexagonal array.

Comment: what's 'hex' in the code above? I could use a PopupMenu instead of RadioButton for choices. Tx.

Comment: @PFD Sorry, I seem to be making a lot of copy/paste errors recently.